# referencing properties in <broker> portion of the activemq.xml configuration

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible to reference my own properties inside the <broker> configuration portion of the activemq.xml file?

I'm setting my property values by altering the ACTIVEMQ_OPTS in the "env" script, e.g. adding something like:

```
ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="${ACTIVEMQ_OPTS} -Dmy.property=MyValue"
```

And I have the following at the start of my activemq.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
  <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Configuring <beans> in the activemq.xml file works fine with my own properties in the "value", e.g. this works fine:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyClass">
    <property name="someProperty" value="${my.property}"/>
</bean>
```

and ${my.property} is resolved perfectly ... but I just can't figure out how to get my properties to resolve when inside the <broker> element or one of it's children (like the persistenceAdapter).

For example, in the following case ...

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <replicatedLevelDB directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb" zkAddress="${my.zk.address}" zkPath="/activemq" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0" weight="${my.weight}"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

... the ${activemq.data} property is resolved ... but I can't seem to figure out how to get any of my own properties to resolve within the <broker> element of the activemq.xml configuration file ... I just keep getting an error that '${my.weight}' isn't a valid number (which is kind of insulting, if you think about it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am stuck with the same problem

Got it to work but not sure if that is the right way.

You have to add it to the startup scripts.

If you are using active.bat

```
"%_JAVACMD%" %ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START% %ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS% %ACTIVEMQ_OPTS% %ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS% 
-Dactivemq.classpath="%ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH%" 
-Dactivemq.home="%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%" 
-Dactivemq.base="%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%" 
-Dactivemq.conf="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%" 
-Dactivemq.data="%ACTIVEMQ_DATA%" 
-Djava.io.tmpdir="%ACTIVEMQ_TMP%" 
-D**remote.host.ip=1.2.3.4** 
-jar "%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/bin/activemq.jar" %*
```

If you are using wrapper, add it to **wrapper.conf**

```
wrapper.java.additional.**13**=-Dremote.host.ip="1.2.3.4"
```

Make sure to increment bolded number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use property placeholders to load a properties file or use environment variables. It looks like you are using Spring, so you'd need to use the Spring-specific property placeholder mechanism.

Property file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
         <property name="properties">
 ...
```

Environment variables:

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

Also see:
[Spring property placeholders](http://www.summa.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring)

Comment: Matt, I have the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean like you show ... that is how I'm able to get the ${my.property} to resolve when I use it in the "value" attribute of another bean.

My problem is that the properties don't resolve when inside the &lt;broker> element of the activemq.xml config file. Well, not entirely true ... the ${activemq.*} properties do resolve but not mine. I did try a trick to start my property name with "activemq." (e.g. -Dactivemq.my.property=foo) and then refer to ${activemq.my.property} inside the &lt;broker> element ... but that didn't work

Comment: I've edited the title of my question and added in the PropertyPlaceholderConifgurer bean that I'm using for some clarification